# How to loop through and display API data containing a JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, rest, object

[Live CodeSandbox link.](https://codesandbox.io/s/gyxff?file=/js/app.js)

I'm trying to access and pull in data from an API, specifically the price text value below:

```
"price": {
  "currency": "CAD",
  "text": "500"
},
```

**JS code** (everything else pulls in fine, just the `<p>${product.price.text}</p>` I'm having trouble with):

```
// Fetch Data
async function getData() {
  const res = await fetch(url);
  const data = await res.json();
  let output = "";
  // Loop through first 'groups' array
  data.groups.map(function (group) {
    // Loop through each 'equipments' array
    group.equipments.map((product) => {
      // Define below variable to match cat products only
      const catProducts =
        product["dealer-name"] === "CATERPILLAR FINANCIAL SERVICES CORPORATION";
      // If the dealer name is everything but cat products (aka only battlefield products)..
      if (!catProducts) {
        // Loop through each 'photos' array
        product.photos.map(() => {
          // Then output the data
          // If year is undefined, replace with empty string
          output += `
            <div class="card">
            <img class="img-fluid" src=${product.photos[0].text} alt=${
            product.model
          } />
            <div class="card--body">
              <h3>${product.year ?? ""} ${product.manufacturer} ${
            product.model ?? ""
          }</h3>
              <p>${product.city ?? "City Not Available"}, ${product.state}</p>
              <p>${product.hours} hours</p>
              <p>${product.price.text}</p> <--- Not working
              <a href='https://used.ca/en/${product["group-code"]}/${
            product["serial-number"]
          }' class="btn btn-primary">View Details</a>
              </div>
            </div>         
        `;
        });
      }
    });
  });
  // Add to slider
  $(".used-slider").slick("slickAdd", output);
}

getData();
```

Currently throwing a console error: "*app.js:26 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'text')*"

**API structure:**

```
{
  "version": "5",
  "company-code": "N001",
  "language-code": "en-CA",
  "total-count": 148,
  "created-date": "2021-09-22T18:12:03.2387128+00:00",
  "template-identifier": "4da31196-7f4b-4529-b832-90d40ef4a024",
  "group-type-code": "ProductFamilyCategory",
  "groups": [
    {
      "group-code": "Backhoe Loaders - Chargeuses-pelleteuses",
      "group-name": "Backhoe Loaders",
      "group-display-name": "Backhoe Loaders",
      "count": 7,
      "equipments": [
        {
          "id": "4536522",
          "dealer-name": "DEALER NAME",
          "GroupName": "Compact Track Loader",
          "product-family-code": "CTL",
          "product-family": "COMPACT TRACK LOADER",
          "product-family-display-name": "Compact Track Loader",
          "manufacturer-code": "CAT",
          "manufacturer": "MANUFACTURER",
          "model": "RUBBER TRACKS FOR CTL 259D ",
          "serial-number": "XXXXX",
          "year": "2016",
          "hours": 0,
          "city": "Ville St-laurent, Montréal",
          "state": "QC",
          "certification": "None",
          "availability": "Available",
          "price": {
            "currency": "CAD",
            "text": "500"
          },
          "product-family-categories": {},
          "photos": [
            {
              "text": "https://s7d2.scene7.com/is/image/CatUsedProduction/wtk?JHNyYz04ZjRjN2UyYzJkMzFmZWNjY2NiZDQ1MTc2NTA4MGY3MiYkdHh0PUJBVFRMRUZJRUxEJTIwRVFVSVBNRU5UJTIwUkVOVEFMUyUyMCUyOFFVJUMzJTg5QkVDJTI5JjUxMTY2"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Anyone know why I'm unable to access the price text value but can access all the others?

Comment: It won't change the results, but you should use `forEach()` instead of `map()` if you're not using the returned array.

Comment: The error indicates that sometimes there isn't a `price` property in `product`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error implies that some products don't have a `price` property. You need to check for this before trying to access the `text` property. You can display a default placeholder instead.

You can use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to simplify this.

```
<p>${product.price?.text || "unknown"}</p> <--- Not working
```

Comment: I've updated the code you suggested, I now receive the error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'text'). Any idea?

Comment: That's not possible, the whole point of conditional chaining is to prevent that error.

Comment: Isn't that the same error you were originally getting?